# Multiple Screen Resolution in android with titanium appcelerator?

Tags: android, titanium, screen, resolution

Hii all,

I am implementing the Multiple screen resolution support in android with titanium appcelerator .for that i am putting images althouse corresponding folders and i am giving 
    //in tiapp.xml file settings.

```
  <manifest>
   <application android:debuggable="true"/>
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
   <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true"        android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
   </manifest>  
//Ui controls are not fitting exactly. 

in tiapp.xml it is working fine in all screens but when i am running in 53 the UI was distabed .please see and let me know further details  for design Screen for s3  in android  .send me any useful information or sample code so that i will fallow and continue....
```

thanks in advance.....